# Overlapping probability of two normal distribution tfp.distributions.Normal()

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

How to calculate overlap probability of two tfp.distributions.Normal?

Like the one implemented within
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist

Answer (score 2):

here is my implementation based on statistics.NormalDiststatistics.NormalDist code:

````
    dv = Y.variance() - X.variance()
    dm = tf.math.abs(Y.mean() - X.mean())

    if tf.reduce_sum(dv) == 0:
         return 1.0 - tf.math.erf(
             tf.math.divide(dm,        
                            tf.math.multiply(
                                tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32),
                                tf.math.multiply(
                                    X.stddev(),
                                    tf.math.sqrt(tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32))))))
    a = tf.math.multiply(X.mean(), Y.variance()) - tf.math.multiply(Y.mean(), X.variance())
    b = tf.math.multiply(
            tf.math.multiply(X.stddev(), Y.stddev()), 
            tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.pow(dm, 2) + tf.math.multiply(
                dv,
                tf.math.log(Y.variance() / X.variance()))))
    x1 = (a + b) / dv
    x2 = (a - b) / dv

    return 1.0 - (tf.math.abs(Y.cdf(x1) - X.cdf(x1)) + tf.math.abs(Y.cdf(x2) - X.cdf(x2)))def norm_dist_overlap_prob_v1(X: tfp.distributions.Normal, Y: tfp.distributions.Normal):  
    dv = Y.variance() - X.variance()
    dm = tf.math.abs(Y.mean() - X.mean())

    if tf.reduce_sum(dv) == 0:
         return 1.0 - tf.math.erf(
             tf.math.divide(dm,        
                            tf.math.multiply(
                                tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32),
                                tf.math.multiply(
                                    X.stddev(),
                                    tf.math.sqrt(tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32))))))
    a = tf.math.multiply(X.mean(), Y.variance()) - tf.math.multiply(Y.mean(), X.variance())
    b = tf.math.multiply(
            tf.math.multiply(X.stddev(), Y.stddev()), 
            tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.pow(dm, 2) + tf.math.multiply(
                dv,
                tf.math.log(Y.variance() / X.variance()))))
    x1 = (a + b) / dv
    x2 = (a - b) / dv

    return 1.0 - (tf.math.abs(Y.cdf(x1) - X.cdf(x1)) + tf.math.abs(Y.cdf(x2) - X.cdf(x2)))```
````

Comment: You can replace things like `tf.math.divide` with the infix `/` operator; similar for `multiply` => `*`. Looks like there are two copies of the function. Also, if you wanted to send a PR to add `overlap_prob` to `tfp.distributions.Normal`, this seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You might do well to watch Pierre Jacob's [excellent series on couplings](https://sites.google.com/site/pierrejacob/cmclectures). If I understand correctly, the integral you want to compute here is connected to the total variation distance.

I have a little demo of sampling max-coupled distributions with TFP here https://colab.research.google.com/gist/brianwa84/2b78eb819ad9cfb910f9a6eb62b4a402/maximal-couplings.ipynb

I don't know off hand if the integral is analytically tractable or not.